# Can we add php contact form in volusion eCommerce site?

Tags: volusion

Can we add php contact form in volusion eCommerce site?

I tried to implement but couldn't get it right.

Problem seems to me is, when calling the php file for form action to "XXX.php" file, it displays error (i.e. couldn't find the page).

Can I call "xxx.php" file from volusion "default.html" page??

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can if your server will support it. What I mean by that is that Volusion is written in ASP.NET and runs on a Microsoft server. PHP on the other hand runs on a LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) server.

Generally I don't find servers running both the LAMP stack and the Microsoft stack but its possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I couldn't call it directly but able to make ti work by putting in the iframe.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question's a bit old but I thought I'd give you my thoughts on it anyways, You asked if you could use PHP on volusion and my answer to that is Unfortunately Not.  Volusion only supports classic ASP and JavaScript on the front end of your store. (And as the previous poster said, it is written in asp.net however I've never been able to get .net code to work in it, it seems .net is only used for the admin panel and for the webservices API...)

Regardless, there are a few other ways to accomplish what you want to do; at least in my mind.

You could possibly add it with an Iframe.

If not, (if volusion blocks out your iframe, or if you just don't want an iframe) I would suggest just making your contact form in ASP or JS... You could view the following link for information on how to use their VSMPT ASP class.. http://support.volusion.com/article/vsmtp-key

If neither of the previous options work, you might also consider making the contact form be part of a new ticket.  It would however require your customers to create an account first, and if it's purpose is to reach new customers you might want to look into how you add custom fields to the account registration form in volusion.  This way you can have the information that you wish to collect from customers inside of your volusion admin panel.

This link may be helpful for the latter. http://support.volusion.com/article/use-custom-fields-gather-marketing-data

I wish you the best of luck working with volusion, I'm stuck on their disgusting software and sure wish I would have known the massive limitations and roadblocks, prior to starting using their product.  Hopefully I'll be moving away soon! I suggest the same to anyone else on it. (sorry for the added two cents)